# Average kinetic energy in 1 dimension according to Maxwell-Boltzmann Distribution

Tags: thermodynamics, particle-physics, energy, statistical-mechanics

The format of the 3 dimensional MB distribution is $A \cdot e^{-\frac{E}{k_BT}} \cdot g(E)$ in which $A$ can be derived using normalization (integration up to $\infty$ must be 1) and $g(E)$ being the degeneracy according to $g(E)=\frac{V\pi \cdot 2^{2.5}m^{1.5}}{h^3}$

The 3 dimensional average kinetic energy $\bar E$ of a particles system can then be calculated by multiplying this MB distribution with $E$ and integrating it over infinity, which yields:
$$\bar E = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{2}{\sqrt \pi} \cdot (\frac{1}{k_BT})^{\frac{3}{2}} \cdot e^{-\frac{E}{k_BT}} \cdot \sqrt{E} \cdot E \cdot dE = \frac{3}{2}k_BT$$

The format for the 1 dimensional MB distribution (e.g. the x-coordinate) is $A\cdot e^{-\frac{E_x}{k_BT}}$ where $A$ is derived by normalizing the integration to 1, which gives $A= \frac{1}{k_BT}$ When calculating the 1 dimensional average energy $\bar E_x$, this MB distribution should also be multiplied by the energy $E_x$ and integrated up to $\infty$ which gives:
$$\bar E_x=\int^{\infty}_0 \frac{1}{k_BT}\cdot e^{-\frac{E_x}{k_BT}}\cdot E_x\cdot dE = k_BT$$
But this should be $\frac{1}{2}k_BT$ instead. The peculiar thing is that when writing $E_x$ in terms of $\frac{1}{2}mv_x^2$ within the formula $A\cdot e^{-\frac{E_x}{k_BT}}$, normalizing $A$ to *that*, multiplying the formula with $\frac{1}{2}mv_x^2$ and integrating it up to $\infty$, then one would indeed get $\frac{1}{2}k_BT$.
$$\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\sqrt{2m}}{\sqrt{\pi k_BT}}\cdot e^{-\frac{mv_x^2}{2k_BT}}\cdot \frac{1}{2}mv_x^2 \cdot dv=\frac{1}{2}k_BT$$
But it wasn't necessary for the 3 dimensional MB distribution to write the format down in terms of $v$ to get the correct average kinetic energy.

Why does the 1 dimensional MB distribution in terms of $E_x$ give an incorrect average energy and how would one realise that this is the wrong way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to take into account $g(E)$ in the calculation for the $1\mathrm{D}$ case. Actually, $g(E) \propto 1/\sqrt{E}$ in that case, which will lead to a different (and hopefully correct) answer.

The reason why you get a different answer by using $v_x$ as your integration variable is because the integrand $\propto \exp \left(-\frac{1mv^2}{2kT} \right) \frac{1}{2}mv^2 $, when changing the variable to $E \propto v^2$, has to be multiplied by $\frac{dv}{dE} \propto 1/\sqrt{E}$ which gives you back the degeneracy factor $g(E)$.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken, the degeneracy factor for the one-dimensional case is $g(E)=2$, since two free particles moving with the same speed but opposite directions ($-\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ and $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$) have the same kinetic energy.
In that case, the normalizing factor $A$ would be $1/(2k_B T)$ and you would obtain your desired result.

Comment: I don't understand why the factor 2 should be in the denominator instead of the numerator. If there's a degeneracy of 2, shouldn't the formula be multiplied by 2 instead of a half?

Comment: You multiply first as in your first equation: $2A \exp{[-E/(k_B T)]}$, then normalize to obtain $A$. It follows that $A=1/(2k_B T)$.

Comment: Thanks. This makes me think though, why isn't it necessary to take into account the different directions for the 3 dimensional formula $A \cdot e^{-\frac{E}{k_BT}} \cdot g(E)$? From what I understand, the degeneracy $g(E)$ only takes into account the different combination values of $E_x$, $E_y$ and $E_z$ that give the same sum, but not the $2$ different possible directions of each of them, which should be $8$ as a total (2 for each of the 3 degrees of freedom)

Comment: Also, I noticed something regarding the multiplication with $2$ because of the two opposite directions. If there are two directions, then the 1D distribution should be $2A \cdot e^{-\frac{E}{k_BT}}$ and normalizing would give indeed $A= 1/(2k_BT)$. The formula would then be $2 \cdot \frac{1}{2k_BT} \cdot e^{-\frac{E}{k_BT}}$. But this simplifies again to $\frac{1}{k_BT} \cdot e^{-\frac{E}{k_BT}}$.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed yesterday my answer is probably wrong (sorry about that). Now I'm at work but I will try to study this later today!

Comment: I checked it and your answer is indeed correct. I should add the $\frac{1}{2}$ factor after normalizing $A$. What I find weird though is, isn't $\frac{k_BT}{2}$ the average energy in only _one_ direction of velocity? If so, shouldn't a degree of freedom take _both_ directions into account such that the average energy of each degree of freedom should be $k_BT$?

Comment: @JohnnyGui I'm very sorry but I've been quite busy lately and couldn't check your comments thoroughly... As for your last comment, because of the equipartition theorem, every degree of freedom which appears squared in the Hamiltonian has an average energy of $k_B T/2$, and here degree of freedom means spatial or velocity components (which take into account both directions), for example.

Comment: I don't think changing the degeneracy term by a constant factor should lead to a different answer. If it was the case, you would probably expect $h$ and $V$ to show up in the final result since they appear in $g(E)$. Only the $E$ dependency of $g(E)$ matters when you're calculation the mean energy of a particle, and I think the mistake in the author's calculation comes from the fact that $g(E) \propto 1/\sqrt{E}$ in 1D.